# Can't disable bootstrap modal windows

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Using twitter bootstrap I want to conditionally disable the modal windows that it calls. I have this function:

Link like:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#contact">Contact</a>
```

JS like:

```
if (Modernizr.touch){
$("a[data-toggle='modal']").each(function() {
    this.href = this.href.replace('/#', '/');
    $(this).data('toggle', '');
});
}
```

I have this script included before bootstrap.min.js is loaded, but still when I click on the links now nothing happens. I think that it's related to the data-toggle attribute, but I have no idea how else to get rid of it.

Thinking of switching it and trying to add the attribute, but I doubt that will work (for the same reason) and I'd prefer not to have to change the markup.

Comment: As a side note, are you trying to replace `#contact` with `/contact` in that replace? I think you have an extra `/` in there.

Comment: I think the href must come out as the full url path, because that aspect is working  proper

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try:

```
$(this).removeAttr("data-toggle");
```